# Possible to Check File Size Before Issuing Command?

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a way to test the file "resume.txt", before executing the attached if/else statement. Is there a way to check and see if the file exsists and if its size is > 0KB? ... I want to exit the program if the file is =< 0KB. Is this possible?

```
if exist C:\Job\Resume.txt (
   echo INPUT FILE C:\Job\Resume.txt
   echo OUTPUT FILE %JOB_RESUME_LOC%\%FILE_DATETIME%_info.dat
   copy C:\Job\Resume.txt%JOB_RESUME_LOC%\%FILE_DATETIME%_info.dat
   echo File Resume.txt copied
) else (
   echo File Resume.txt not copied
)
```

Basically, If the file "Resume.txt" is 0KB, exit the program. Otherwise, continue running the program. I hope this was not too confusing!

Comment: you can get the file size with `for %%a in (resume.txt) do set size=%%~za` and compare it with a simple `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line of batch script.

```cmd
@Where/T C:\Job:Resume.txt 2>Nul|Find /V " 0 ">Nul||Exit/B 1
```

This will exit the entire script if the file doesn't exist or has a size of zero. Then you just need to put your normal script underneath that line.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Stephan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964232/possible-to-check-file-size-before-issuing-command#comment67208419_39964232):

```
for %%a in ("C:\Job\Resume.txt") do set /A size=%%~za + 0
if %size% GTR 0 (
   echo INPUT FILE C:\Job\Resume.txt
   echo OUTPUT FILE %JOB_RESUME_LOC%\%FILE_DATETIME%_info.dat
   copy "C:\Job\Resume.txt" %JOB_RESUME_LOC%\%FILE_DATETIME%_info.dat
   echo File Resume.txt copied
) else (
   echo File Resume.txt not copied
)
```

For explanation, read `call /?` and [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Next quoted statement is applied to `%a` parameter:

> `%~za`  expands `%a` to size of file

If `"C:\Job\Resume.txt"` file does not exists, then `%~za` expands to an empty string. 
Hence, `set /A size=%%~za + 0` returns `0`.